# Recode in R not producing desired output

Tags: r, recode

I'm trying to recode age variables into three categroies in R but it's not allocating them properly:

```
data_2017_18$ageband3 <- 
dplyr::recode(data_2017_18$age, '1:30' = 1L, 
'31:50' = 2L, '51:99' = 3L)
```

I'd assume the crosstab with age would be:

ageband
1
2
3

However, when I look at the dataset, it's putting everybody's age value into an 'ageband3' variable.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Are youtrying to transform values for 1:30 into 1, 31:50 into 2, etc. ? In that case, you are looking for the `cut` function

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm hoping to do - any pointers, please? Cheers

Comment: The _pointer_ was given to you: try the `cut` function. Once you arrive there, you only need to figure out the `breaks` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need for `recode`. The easiest solution is to use `cut`:

```r
data_2017_18$ageband3 <- cut(data_2017_18$age, cut(1:100, breaks = c(0, 30,50, Inf))
```

Use `cut(data_2017_18$age, breaks = c(0, 30,50, Inf), labels = c(1,2,3))` if your prefer labelling your levels 1,2 and 3. But `R` handles quite well interval values (`[0,30]` for instance)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with:

data_2017_18$ageband3 <- cut(data_2017_18$age,
                          breaks = c(0, 30, 50, Inf),
                          labels = c(1,2,3))

Answer (score 0):

there're many ways to go about this task in R and here's my suggestion
 `tibble(age=1:99L) %>% 
    mutate(age_recoded=if_else(age %in% c(1:30),1L,
                       if_else(age %in% c(31:50),2L,3L))) %>% 
    count(age_recoded)`. I hope that helps.